# Does Ignite Source Kafka Connector provide topic partitioning of data?

Tags: apache-kafka, ignite

We are trying to push Ignite events using IgniteSourceConnector producer. But due to a high load and only one partition, we are getting so much lag at times and it may not be the best solution for us in the future.

So we are planning to have multiple consumer groups but since we would be having only one partition, it would cause consistency problems as we need the queue ordering.

Can someone please suggest an idea for this? Can we have multiple partitions configuration for topics via IgniteSourceConnector

Comment: All Kafka connectors support partitioning, but if you need ordering without some key, then you cannot have multiple partitions

Comment: I don't think IgniteSourceConnector configuration has partition support.

Answer (score 0):

Topic Partitions are not able to be set from config.

You can find [the source code](https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/blob/master/modules/kafka-ext/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/stream/kafka/connect/IgniteSourceTask.java#L167) uses a Map for the "source partitions" (from Ignite) that are hard-set to `"cache"`, and a null Kafka record key, therefore the Kafka Producer of the Connect API will round-robin all records into the outgoing topic for as many partitions as it may have.

Comment: By your statement can I say, in real-time it uses only one partition for a topic?

Comment: No, the partition is determined by the record key (which is null), and therefore will round-robin, like my answer says

Comment: Thanks. one doubt. while creating topic if I create n number of partitions all the data will be pushed to those partitions in a round robin way? If so, I can't control which message is to be pushed to which partition?

Comment: That's correct, based on what I read in the source code of the connector. However, you may be able to use `ExtractField$Key` transforms to solve that